# Can one preserve the appearance of the HorizontalGauge?

Tags: gui-construction

I use sometimes the `HorizontalGauge` instead of a slider in `Manipulate`or instead of the `ProgressIndicator`. I find it very convenient, since it gives quantitative information on the status of the calculation. During performing the calculation it looks as it is expected:
[image]

However, when I close a notebook and then open it once more, it looks as follows:

[image]

Which is, generally, ugly.

Is there a way to preserve its form, so that it has the former performance also after closing/opening of the notebook?

**Edit**: To address the question of Kuba, a simplistic code with the described behavior is given below. It shows the use of the `HorizontalGauge` instead of the `ProgressIndicator`to monitor the solution of a differential equation:

```
    Clear[x, y, data, k];
data = {{0, 1}};
k = 0;
HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[k], {0, 30}]
Dynamic[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 31}, {0, 1.2}}]]
NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}, 
  StepMonitor :> (Pause[.02]; Set[k, x]; AppendTo[data, {x, y[x]}])];
```

On the screen one should see the following:

[image]

The `HorizontalGauge`here shows the state of the solution of the differential equation. After evaluation it has the canonical appearance. However, after closing/opening of the notebook its appearance changes.

Another example is the use of the gauge in Manipulate:

```
 Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], {{a, 1}, 0, 6.28, 
  VerticalGauge[##, ImageSize -> 50] &}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Here in contrast to the previous case the `VerticalGauge` preserves its appearance even after closing/opening of the notebook.

Comment: @Kuba Please see the edit.

Comment: I see. When the plot is done I'm saving the nb and closing MMA, after reopening it looks ok, only plot doesn't due to the fact that `data` doesn't exist anymore. I'm on Win10 V10.3.1

Comment: @Kuba Yes, exactly. But my main concern is not the plot, but the appearance of the gauge. I gave one more example of the gauge use in Manipulate. There everything is OK, the appearance persists the closing/opening of the notebook.

Comment: Yes, I know, my point was, the gauge looks ok in my case.

Comment: @Kuba, Well I have Win7/Mma10.3

Comment: `SaveDefinitions -> True`  works for `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule`, so you could use one of those, or use an explicit `Initialization->` option for your `Dynamic`.

Comment: @Yves Klett I tried this: `HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[k, Initialization :> (k = 45)], {43, 48}]` in one of my calculations. Without success, however. Did I miss something?

Comment: Cannot test right now. I guess the initialization really needs to contain everything that is necessary for evaluation (that is the way it works with `Manipulate` etc).

Comment: @Yves Klett Could you please kindly give an example, say, within the case given above in my edit?

Comment: In version 9, the following happened: when I saved and reopened the notebook, the gauge had the distorted appearance you show, but the "Enable Dynamics" prompt also appeared at the top of the notebook. When the "Enable" button was clicked, the gauge went back to its proper appearance. So, one could solve it by having the notebook in a trusted path, or at least by allowing the prompt to appear. Did you perhaps disable the prompt (set `"TrustByDefault"` to `False` rather than `Automatic`)?

Comment: @Oleksandr R. Thank you, but no. In my case `"TrustByDefault"` is set to `Automatic`and cannot be changed. Further, if I press the "Enable Dynamics" button, the appearance becomes right, as you described. This is OK, until I only work with the notebook myself. It becomes unsatisfactory, when I need to distribute the notebook among other people, which is the case.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. You are right about the Manipulate/Gauge situation, I noticed it only now, even `SaveDefinitions->True`does not help.

Comment: I deleted that comment because I noticed that if you have only the `HorizontalGauge` and `VerticalGauge` in a notebook, without any additional `Dynamic` or `Manipulate` around them, then both of them will appear correctly before enabling dynamics. It appears that the problem only relates to them being constructed based on unevaluated dynamic values and is not inherent to the gauges themselves.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. That means in fact that one cannot use the gauges in the same way as one can use, say, sliders. I mean that with the Manipulate using sliders the `SaveDefinitions->True` option preserves the appearance. This is a pity, since the gauge appearance is more convenient.

Comment: A slider is drawn by the OS and not by *Mathematica*, so the scope for it to have a distorted appearance is much more limited. If you're very concerned with presentation, you might like to consider inquiring with WRI how the notebook can be signed, which would enable dynamic features by default even if the notebook is in an untrusted path.